# Train and Test on user_id as input

Tags: machine-learning, python

Is is possible to train and test a model based on individual user_id. I want my model to take a user id as input, to train the data on history of the same user and make predictions for each individual user

Answer (score 0):

It's of course possible to train a model with user_id, although it's more common for doing it on historical data. You probably don't need the user_id information. Please check.